# VB .net with DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() passing only first row data to database, even i have 3 row.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Nage(GName,GAge)values(@GName,@Gage)", mycon)
Dim g1name As String
Dim g2age As String
For x As Integer = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
        g1name = DGV1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
        g2age = DGV1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gname", g1name)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gage", g2age)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

i am trying to add data from datagridview to access database
Datagridview have 3 row data but cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() passing only first row data to database, even i have 3 row.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Nage(GName,GAge)values(@GName,@Gage)", mycon)

Dim g1name As String
Dim g2age As String
For x As Integer = 0 To DGV1.Rows.Count - 1
        g1name = DGV1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
        g2age = DGV1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gname", g1name)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gage", g2age)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

i want to add all rows data to database

Comment: Set breakpoints and step through the code, you should see it after the first loop... This is a debug problem that you should be able to catch if you step through. Turn `Option Strict On` as well and fix your problems, wrap your connections and commands in `using` statements and or make sure to dispose of them and dont use `AddWithValue` use `Add`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a loop at all. Create a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid, then use a data adapter to save the entire contents of the `DataTable` to the database in one go. You can build the schema of the `DataTable` manually or you can do it with a call to `FillSchema` on the same data adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The first time your loop runs it adds 2 parameters to the parameters collection. Everything is fine because you reference 2 parameters in your Sql statement (@GName and @Gage). On the next iteration of your loop for the second record you want to add, 2 more parameters are added to the parameters collection. Now you have 4 parameters but only 2 in your Sql statement. See the problem? Move the addition of parameters outside the loop so they only get added once and just change the Value of the parameters in the loop.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'The Using blocks ensure that your database objects
    'are closed and disposed even if there is an error
    Using mycon As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into Nage(GName, GAge) values(@GName, @Gage)", mycon)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GName", OleDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gage", OleDbType.VarChar)
            mycon.Open()
            'Changed to a For Each to save a little typing
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV1.Rows
                cmd.Parameters("@Gname").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
                cmd.Parameters("@Gage").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

It is important to note that with OleDb it is the order of the parameters that is important, not the names. When you get to Sql Server names become important.

If you wish to investigate Data Binding, Data Adapters etc., you will find that you can update your database without the loop by DataAdpater.Update().

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim oledbAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim oledbCmdBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sql As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Your mdb filename;"
        connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
        Sql = "select * from tblUsers"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            oledbAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
            oledbAdapter.Fill(ds)
            DataGridView1.Data Source= ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            oledbCmdBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(oledbAdapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                oledbAdapter.Update(ds.Tables(0))
            End If
            ds.AcceptChanges()
            MsgBox("Save changes")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

http://vb.net-informations.com/dataadapter/dataadapter-datagridview-oledb.htm